# Why large div centered via "margin" trick is cut from left side

Tags: css, html

I have a very strange problem with div centering, I was able to narrow to this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AJmSw/1/). Basically I have very large div (3000px) and I want to center it in the page. I used the old good trick with negative margin:

```
.my_div
{
    width:3000px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-1500px;
}
```

I was more than shocked to discover that this cuts left-most part of the div (tested in Firefox 25 and Chrome 30) when browser window is smaller than 3000 px. I am surely missing something obvious as I use this trick for few years and never had any issue with it...

**EDIT:** To clarify, I don't want scroll centered, I want the div centered (in case the div is smaller than window). If the div is larger, than being scrolled to leftmost is perfectly fine for me I just need to not cut the div by browser. I am testing with 3000px, but actual div in my page has size of 1100px and the problem is very real there

Comment: How would you expect it to be centered without cutting off the invisible portion?

Comment: @MightyPork I want to be able to scroll left to see rest of the page...

Comment: @ExplosionPills On both Firefox 25 and Chrome 30 I can't

Comment: Yeah it's cutting it off. I can't see "Lorem ipsum...". Firebug says the width of the element is NaN.

Comment: it's obviusly cutted you can't center the scroll position only with css.... so you really want the scroll centered

Comment: @Danko I don't want scroll centered, I want the div centered (in case the div is smaller than window). If the div is larger, than being scrolled to leftmost is perfectly fine for me I just need to not cut the div by browser. I am testing with 3000px, but actual div in my page has size of 1100px and the problem is very annoying there.

Comment: Maybe you should just use Javascript. After the page loads, get the width of the window and center the element that way. This CSS hack for centering absolutely position elements just doesn't work in this case.

Comment: @MatthewRapati Is there any CSS trick to center div on page? To be honest, I am not up to date with CSS 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`margin: 0 auto;` should center the div for you.

I updated your fiddle to include margin:0 auto; instead of left:50%; etc.

I also added a smaller div that is also using margin:0 auto; to display how it would work with a smaller div.

[Let me know if this isn't what you're looking for and I can try to help you further.](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/AJmSw/6/)

Comment: it's working, but I have one more question - can I move a bit element that is centered? I mean something that works like `left:50%; width:100px; margin-left:-60px` , moving element 10px left from it's centered position?